# Read header dwg file format

Tags: cad, dwg

I am reading a header from dwg file format release 2004, the Open Design Specification for .dwg files Version 5.4.1, page 26: The next 0x14 bytes will be copied from the magic number sequence, starting at 0x100 – 0x14.
I have this buffer: address "0xEC" : "f8466a0496730ed9162f6768d4f74a4ad0576876"
If I split in 2 digits, almost all of them is not in magic number sequence.

Then 4.3 System section page: A System Section page starts with of the following 0x14 bytes of header data. I suppose they are different address.
For this address 0x100 I have this buffer: "5056070062526441eb526441cb5264416b526441"
I understand they are different addresses, but I don't understand where come 0x6C value from ?.

In 0x100 the first 4 bytes should be: Section page map: 0x41630e3b or Section map: 0x4163003b, my values are very different and they are from a valid dwg file release 2004.

Thanks for your help

In 0x100 the first 4 bytes should be: Section page map: 0x41630e3b or Section map: 0x4163003b, my values are very different and they are from a valid dwg file release 2004.